# Hold a row in UItableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a plenty of records and on selection of particular row I want to make this row hold , like sticky header.

As per example I have 100 records in my array. My UITableView displays 10 records at a time. Now I select 3rd row. When I scroll tableview 3rd row should be on top of all the records while scrolling. How does it possible? [Please refer attachment snap](http://mediacdn.disqus.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/223/1420/original.jpg).

I am using cocoa control [MDSpreadView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdspreadview). If anyone know about it, must help. You can give answer based on UITableView. Any type of suggestions are acceptable.

Comment: Do you require the cell to actually stick to the view so that is it not scrolled with the others?

Comment: @nickfalk : Yes. thats what I am looking for

Comment: As cells are just viewObjects, couldn't you simply add it as a subview to your tableView's superview?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a section header, which looks like your cell.
Check [– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a).
When you select a cell init a section header view like your cells look like. Note that you want section header but the tableview's header, because the last one won't be hold on top if it's not visible.